# How to change <div> property of certain content panel in a php webpage?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row text-center">

    <?php
    if($_GET[id] == 0)
    {
        $querysb = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM services WHERE parentid !=0 order by parentid, cid ");
    }
    else
    {
        $querysb = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM services WHERE parentid='".$_GET[id]."'");
    }
    while($rowsb = mysql_fetch_assoc($querysb))
    {
        if($val == '6' || $val =='10'){
            $classname = 'whitebg';
        } else {
            $classname = 'bg-blue co-white';
        }
    ?>

          <div class="col-md-4 mrgnBtm15">
            <div class="<?php echo $classname;?> padding30" style="min-height: 250px">
             <h3 class="service-heading">
                <?php echo $rowsb['cname'];?>
              </h3>
              <h4>
                RS <?php echo $rowsb['price'];?><br>
              </h4>
              <div class="mrgnTop15 clearfix"></div>

              <a  class="btn bg-orange co-white" href="<?php echo MYWEBSITE;?>servicedetail/<?php echo to_prety_url($rowsb['cname']).'-'.$rowsb['cid'];?>.html">
                  <font style="size:14px; color:#000; font-weight:bolder;font-family: "Open Sans";">Register</font></a>

            </div>
          </div>
<?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am working on a dynamic website. here is the code of a particular page. In this page there is a div section with class="col md-4". If the number of content panel in that division appears to **5** or **7** in that case I want **only** the last panel (i.e 5th and 7th) to be in full column (col-12). What should I do?

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: ThanX @Mangus Eriksson. I really appreciate your advice :-) will you suggest a way to solve the problem i mentioned in question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `col-md-4`, 3 divs will be shown each row. So I think what you are looking for is a way to make the last div full width if its going to be alone in its row. In that case, you will need to make it `col-md-12` on **4th (not 5th)** and 7th and 10th records and so on. This is exactly what the following code does,

I think what you want to do is show the

```
    <?php
    if($_GET[id] == 0)
    {
    $querysb=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM services WHERE parentid !=0 order by parentid, cid ");
    }
    else
    {
    $querysb=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM services WHERE parentid='".$_GET[id]."'");
    }
    $number_of_records = mysql_num_rows($querysb);
    $counter = 1;
    while($rowsb=mysql_fetch_assoc($querysb))
    {
        if($val == '6' || $val =='10'){
            $classname= 'whitebg';
        }else{
            $classname= 'bg-blue co-white';
        }
        //if($number_of_records %3 ==1 && $counter == $number_of_records)
        if(($number_of_records == 5 ||  $number_of_records == 7) && $counter == $number_of_records)
            $col_class = "col-md-12";
        else
            $col_class = "col-md-4";

    ?>

              <div class="<?php echo $col_class;?> mrgnBtm15">
                <div class="<?php echo $classname;?> padding30" style="min-height: 250px">
                 <h3 class="service-heading">
                    <?php echo $rowsb['cname'];?>
                  </h3>
                  <h4>
                    RS <?php echo $rowsb['price'];?><br>
                  </h4>
                  <div class="mrgnTop15 clearfix"></div>

                  <a  class="btn bg-orange co-white" href="<?php echo MYWEBSITE;?>servicedetail/<?php echo to_prety_url($rowsb['cname']).'-'.$rowsb['cid'];?>.html">
                      <font style="size:14px; color:#000; font-weight:bolder;font-family: "Open Sans";">Register</font></a>

                </div>
              </div>
    <?php
    $counter++;
     } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it is not working :-) @amit joshi

Comment: if the number of content panel is 5 then i want to put 5th in col-12. I tried the code you give. but still the 5th content panel appears in col-4.